# Using a subset of classes in ImageNet

Tags: pytorch

I'm aware that subsets of ImageNet exist, however they don't fulfill my requirement. I want 50 classes at their native ImageNet resolutions.

To this end, I used `torch.utils.data.dataset.Subset` to select specific classes from ImageNet. However, it turns out, class labels/indices must be greater than 0 and less than `num_classes`.

Since ImageNet contains 1000 classes, the idx of my selected classes quickly goes over 50. How can I reassign the class indices and do so in a way that allows for evaluation later down the road as well?

Is there a way more elegant way to select a subset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure I understood your conclusions about labels being greater than zero and less than `num_classes`. The [`torch.utils.data.Subset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Subset) helper takes in a `torch.utils.data.Dataset` and a *sequence* of indices, they correspond to indices of data points from the `Dataset` you would like to keep in the subset. These indices have nothing to do with the classes they belong to.

Here's how I would approach this:

1. Load your dataset through [`torchvision.datasets`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/datasets.html) (custom datasets would work the same way). Here I will demonstrate it with FashionMNIST since ImageNet's data is not made available directly through `torchvision`'s API.

   ```
   >>> ds = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST('.')
   >>> len(ds)
   60000
   ```
2. Define the classes you want to select for the subset dataset. And retrieve all indices from the main dataset which correspond to these classes:

   ```
   >>> targets = [1, 3, 5, 9]
   >>> indices = [i for i, label in enumerate(ds.targets) if label in targets]
   ```
3. You have your subset:

   ```
   >>> ds_subset = Subset(ds, indices)
   >>> len(ds_subset)
   24000
   ```
4. At this point, you can use a *dictionnary* to remap your labels using `targets`:

   ```
   >>> remap = {i:x for i, x in enumerate(targets)}
   {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 9}
   ```

   For example:

   ```
   >>> x, y = ds_subset[10]
   >>> y, remap[y] # old_label, new_label
   1, 3
   ```